# .htaccess to get sanitized URLs for portfolio page

Tags: php, .htaccess, url

In order to have sanitized URLs in my domain for SEO purposes, I need to make some adjustments to the .htaccess file but I need some help with it.

I have the next files:

- `./index.php`
- `./work.php`
- `./project-page.php`

And the URL's should be:

- `http://example.com/`
- `http://example.com/work`
- `http://example.com/work/first-project` (project title taken from
  project id)

---

**First question:** Do I need to get the `./project-page.php` file inside a folder named `work` or is it redirected from .htaccess file and how? If the answer is the second, I must replace URLs inside that file such as images and includes, right?

**Second question:** But what if the user gets to `http://example.com/work/`? I get an error that that page does not exist, and I need that to work too. I don't know what's the best practice in this case.

Thanks for your answers!

---

## EDIT:

I already have this config on my .htaccess

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
  RewriteEngine on
  RewriteBase /

  #### PERSISTENT CONTENT ####

  # RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^example.com$ [NC]
  # RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://example.com/$1 [L,R=301]

  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}\.php -f
  RewriteRule ^(.*)$ $1.php


  RewriteRule ^work-(.*)$ project-page.php?id=$1
</IfModule>
```

So right now, I can access to `example.com/work` as `./work.php` and `example.com/work-first-project` as  `./project-page.php?id=1` BUT I want it to be `example.com/work/first-project`

So, is it better to move `./project-page.php` inside a new folder named `/work/` or it's not needed. And how can I get it to work as `example.com/work/first-project` with .htaccess or any other methods.

Answer (score 0):

You want to use RewriteRules, for example these will work for the first two examples:

```
RewriteRule "^/$" "/index.php"
RewriteRule "^/work$" "/work.php"
```

https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/rewrite/intro.html#rewriterule

You can structure your folders however you like so long as the second param points to a valid file.

You can put one RewriteRule before the rest in .htaccess to remove the trailing slash

```
RewriteRule "^(.*)/$" "/$1"
```

You can also use an HTTP301 (permanent) redirect with `R=301`, and ensure no further rules are processed once the redirect with `L`.

```
RewriteRule ^(.*)/$ /$1 [R=301,L]
```

Comment: This is not solving my doubt, adding more info to the main post.

Comment: You'll need to put


`RewriteRule ^work-(.*)$ project-page.php?id=$1`


before


`RewriteRule ^(.*)$ $1.php`


The first one is taking precedence and rewriting the URL, once that happens the second one will no longer match.

Comment: Posted an answer regarding this. It seems it's in the good direction but having trouble now removing file extension.

Answer (score 0):

Cannot get it to work. As Sean suggested, I put the removing trailing slash at the top before the others sentences. Now the thing disrupting the whole document is the last sencence. Which was originally put to remove the file extensions. If I delete that thing, the others work ok.

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
  RewriteEngine on
  RewriteRule ^(.*)/$ /$1 [R=301,L]
  RewriteBase /
  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}\.php -f
  RewriteRule ^work/(.*)$ project-page.php?id=$1 [R=301,L]
  RewriteRule ^(.*)$ $1.php
</IfModule>
```